# I am getting the error Cannot resolve @wallet-standard/app

Tags: solana-wallet-adapter

I am having issues compiling my code. I keep getting the error that @wallet-standard/app cant be resolved in `\node_modules\@solana\wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base\lib\esm`. How can I resolve this issue?

Full error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@solana/wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base/lib/esm/wallet.js 17:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@wallet-standard/app' in 'E:\Programming\...\node_modules\@solana\wallet-standard-wallet-adapter-base\lib\esm'
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
"dependencies": {
    "@solana/pay": "^0.1.0",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-base": "^0.9.19",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react": "^0.15.25",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui": "^0.9.23",
    "@solana/wallet-adapter-wallets": "^0.19.8",
    "@solana/web3.js": "^1.70.1",
    "@strata-foundation/web3-token-auth": "^3.5.4",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "webpack": "^5.75.0"
},
"scripts": {
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.41",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
}
```

}